# Nested while loop in Scheme with Gimp?

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm writing a Gimp Script-Fu script, and trying to use a nested while loop. `x` is set to `15`, `y` is set to `30`. `y` loops up to `35`, yet `x` stays at `15` and the loop quits. What is wrong here? Why is the value of `x` not changed?

```
(while (< x 20)
  (while (< y 35)    
    (gimp-message (string-append (number->string x) "-" (number->string y)))
    (set! y (+ y 1)))
  (set! x (+ x 1)))
```

Comment: I agree with @JasonSperske;  this isn't recursive.  Do you mean nested?

Comment: yes, sorry I meant nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` is never being reset back to `0`. Your code will increment `y` up to `35`, then increment `x` 20 times, however on each subsequent increment of `x` `y` is still set to `35`.

If you wanted to go over each combination of values of `x` and `y` then you would need code more like this:

```
(while (< x 20)
    (set! y 0)
    (while (< y 35)    
            (gimp-message (string-append (number->string x) "-" (number->string y)))
             (set! y (+ y 1))
            )
    (set! x (+ x 1))
)
```

Here is a more complete example now that I've had time to work through this question with Gimp (I'm using `print` instead of `gimp-message` because I'm working in the console, but it should be interchangeable).  To start I'm defining a function called `SO` that accepts the arguments, `x`, `y` that both represents pairs of min and max values:

```
(define (SO x y)
  (let* ((x! (car x)) (y! (car y)))
    (while (< x! (car (cdr x)))
      (set! y! (car y))
      (while (< y! (car (cdr y)))
        (print (string-append (number->string x!) "-" (number->string y!)))
        (set! y! (+ y! 1))
      )
      (set! x! (+ x! 1))
    )
  )
)
```

Inside this function, I'm pulling out the first and last values of `x` and `y` (with `(car x)` and `(car (cdr x))` then I'm using `let* to create two inner variables called`x!`and`y!`that I will be altering the value of (to remove side effects of having`x`and`y` change after the function is called).  If you call this function like so:

```
(SO '(15 20) '(30 35))
```

You get the following output:

```
"15-30"
"15-31"
"15-32"
"15-33"
"15-34"
"16-30"
"16-31"
"16-32"
"16-33"
"16-34"
"17-30"
"17-31"
"17-32"
"17-33"
"17-34"
"18-30"
"18-31"
"18-32"
"18-33"
"18-34"
"19-30"
"19-31"
"19-32"
"19-33"
"19-34"
```

Comment: Actually I see from your question you wanted to start with x=15 and y=30, but I kept these value out of my answer because I think it complicates the more general answer of resetting your inner loop

Comment: Thank you very much! How did I miss that, arggh.

Comment: There, I added a cleaner example and tested it with the Script-fu window in Gimp :) I really love this language and I am having a lot of fun learning it :)